# Where can I find documentation about the python charm helpers?

Tags: python, juju

I would like to have up-to-date documentation about writing charms in python.

Comment: The pythonhosted.org site is the proper place, should we just close this question? I'll take an item to ensure we link to the documentation properly from juju.ubuntu.com

Comment: My biggest problem is that that documentation is incomplete and quite outdated... I downloaded the actual code to have a better understanding of what it does, and I see that the documentation in the code itself is actually more up-to-date...

I also think the juju.ubuntu.com/docs should brag a lot more about the python helpers. They are very handy but guides and tutorials about them are almost nonexistent...

I'll rephrase my question and submit an answer to make it a real question and we can marked it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python charmhelpers api reference](https://pythonhosted.org/charmhelpers/getting-started.html). Although this seems to be a bit outdated.

You can also look at [other charms written in python](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~charmers/charms/precise/mysql/trunk/files) or check out the [charmhelpers code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~charm-helpers/charm-helpers/devel/files) itself.